# Keycloak RBAC for nginx reverse proxy

Tags: keycloak

I started to work with keycloak, and here is a setup I want to test.

I want to test this scenario:
[image: scheme]

It works, but I want to implement role-based access to apps behind Nginx proxy and I can't understand how exactly payload of jwt token generates.

Here is my JWT tokens payload:

```
  "jti": "f5f07b6f-ccae-4f57-a8ea-ae02ebb3cb12",
  "exp": 1569263630,
  "nbf": 0,
  "iat": 1569227630,
  "iss": "https://keycloak.domain.local/auth/realms/LDAP_test",
  "sub": "fedc6baf-4ba4-4fa6-924c-9501edf070f7",
  "typ": "Serialized-ID",
  "auth_time": 0,
  "session_state": "aa0052ee-b5e1-45cc-bee4-e7bccdfa4a59",
  "state_checker": "sC_nvlDXfjUDHhC15ZDpPauX5JkxhvVtYUOn62PhtV8"
```

I want my token to contain roles, username and email and i run out of ideas how to put it there. Is client somehow related to the content of the token or keycloak always gives everything he have into it?

Here are my Nginx client settings:

```
server {
    server_name demo-a.domain.local;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://10.10.10.168/index.html;
           access_by_lua '
             local opts = {
               redirect_uri_path = "/redirect_uri",
               accept_none_alg = true,
               discovery = "https:/keycloak.domain.local/auth/realms/LDAP_test/.well-known/openid-configuration",
               client_id = "nginx-gateway",
               client_secret = "19fe43bc-4167-4433-816a-eb96da33f9a3",
               redirect_uri_scheme = "https",
               logout_path = "/logout",
               redirect_after_logout_uri = "https://keycloak.domain.local/auth/realms/LDAP_test/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=https://www.nginx-gateway.domain.local/",
               redirect_after_logout_with_id_token_hint = false,
               session_contents = {id_token=true}
             }
             -- call introspect for OAuth 2.0 Bearer Access Token validation
             local res, err = require("resty.openidc").authenticate(opts)
             if err then
               ngx.status = 403
               ngx.say(err)
               ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_FORBIDDEN)
             end
          ';
          }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, completely forget about this question, but still here is a solution.

Just use a proper oidc proxy like gatekeeper (louketo now) or oauth2-proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure the [client](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#core-concepts-and-terms) to be openid client? Is it UI or machine client?

To cause your JWT to have roles, one follows usual below flow:

- Create client in Keycloak admin-console and [configure](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#oidc-clients) it to support
  [open-id-connect](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#openid-connect-2).
- Add users to Keycloak.
- Assign roles to users.
- Configure your client to have the client id of Keycloak client.
- Exercise browser or machine flow which involves passing of JWT to the
  client. JWT will contain the roles as claims.

Answer (score 0):

Still debugging it, but here are a few pointers you will definitely need....
You need to be [Authenticating Reverse Proxy with KeyCloak](https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2018/01/11/authenticating-reverse-proxy-with-keycloak/) while using the [keycloak behind an nginx proxy](https://www.mai1015.com/development/2019/05/05/docker-keycloak-proxy-behind-nginx/)